# Can neo4j return some property of node and represent in graph?

Tags: neo4j

If I return node. It can show as graph in neo4j browser.

```
MATCH (p:Parent)<-[A1:IS_PARENT]-(s:Student)<-[A2:IS_GUARDIAN]-(g:Guardian)
RETURN p,s,g,A1,A2
limit 25;
```

But if I return some property of node. It can show only table or text in neo4j browser.

```
MATCH (p:Parent)<-[A1:IS_PARENT]-(s:Student)<-[A2:IS_GUARDIAN]-(g:Guardian)
RETURN p.Firstname,s.Firstname,g.Firstname,A1,A2
limit 25;
```

How can i return some property of node and can show as graph?

Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It only shows *nodes* as a graph, their properties aren't themselves nodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return 'views' of existing nodes, there is 'virtual nodes' (and rels) in APOC.

See https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_virtual

Won't it be a lot of work for the expected result ? I think so, double check your need.
However, thats an occasion to learn a lot